# Error when inserting a document into MongoDB via Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to insert a document into MongoDB in Node.js. I have read from the DB successfully, and added documents via the command-line interface. However, I can't insert a document from JavaScript. If I do, I get an error:

> Error: Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback

Here is my code:

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function(err, db) {
        if (!err) {
            db.collection("test").insert({ str: "foobar" });
        }
    });
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why I get this error.

What did I do wrong, and how should I do this instead?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to provide a callback function to your `insert` call so that the method can communicate any errors that occur during the insert back to you.

```
db.collection("test").insert({ str: "foobar" }, function (err, inserted) {
    // check err...
});
```

Or, if you truly don't care whether the insert succeeds or not, pass a write-concern value of 0 in the options parameter:

```
db.collection("test").insert({ str: "foobar" }, { w: 0 });
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. Can you point me to the documentation for this? All the examples I found didn't seem to be for node. I can't find any examples that work as-is.

Comment: What you're hitting is that before `MongoClient` was introduced, all example code typically used connections where safe-writes mode was off by default, and in that case you're code would have worked.  But `MongoClient` enables safe mode by default.  Note that the example in the `insert` [docs](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#insert) notes that it's not using safe mode.