# Entering data with MongoDb and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I'm trying to enter data into a mongodb collection with node. As far as I can tell I have access to the collection.

```
var collection = db.collection("whatsGoingOnEvents");
if(collection){
console.log("hitting stream");
var stream = collection.find({time: parsedObject.time, endTime: parsedObject.endTime, lon:parsedObject.lon,lat:parsedObject.lat}).stream();
console.log(stream);
stream.on("data",function(data){
    console.log("data");
    console.log(data);
    if(!data){
        collection.insert(parsedObject);
        console.log("hitting insert");
    }
});
stream.on("end",function(){
//dosomething
});
}
```

parsedObject may or may not have all of those fields - should it matter? I thought if the field was not there then collection.find() is just looking for time to be "undefined", which is still technically a value.

I never hit `console.log("data")` so I never insert documents. I've been trying to follow [this link](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html).

and so am not sure why the insert is not happening. I know that nothing is being added `from db.collection.stats();`, which tells me the size of the collection is 0.

Oh also, this is what I'm using to connect to Mongo-

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

EDIT--

I tried the answer below - that resulted in this error-

```
    lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:481
        throw err;
              ^
Error: Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback
    at insertAll (/Users/psanker/Google Drive/Coding/Javascript/WhatsGoingOn/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:332:11)
    at Collection.insert (/Users/psanker/Google Drive/Coding/Javascript/WhatsGoingOn/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:91:3)
```

^The above occurred because I hadn't added a callback to the insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query doesn't match any records (which would seem logical, given that you write that the collection size is 0), the `data` event handler will never get called (because that will only be called when there's an actual result).

I think you're better off with using `findOne` and a regular callback:

```
collection.findOne({ params }, function(err, result) {
  if (err)
    throw err;
  if (result === null) {
    collection.insert(parsedObject, { w: 0 });
  }
});
```

Or even an [`upsert`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#update).

Comment: ah - is there an event that occurs if no result is returned?

Comment: also, that's giving me an error-
Error: Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback

Comment: I don't think there's a 'no results' event, but streams are only really useful for when you run queries which might return lots of results; in this case, the maximum number of results is 1. Wrt your error, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14410066/893780 (I updated my answer accordingly).