# NodeJS: Returning data from an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm trying to write a function to create a new user on my database (mongodb) and then return that user as an object which I defined.  However, since the call to insert the user is async, result.nInserted is always undefined because the async code doesn't finish in time.  Therefore, I never get to return my user.  I would try and use callbacks to fetch the user after it is done being inserted, but then how would I be able to return that data from my original addUser function?

```
User.addUser = function(db, email, username, password, firstname, lastname, company, twitter){
    var _id = new mongodb.ObjectID();

    var result = db.get('users').insert({
        _id: _id,
        email : email,
        verified : false,
        password : password,
        username : username,
        firstname : firstname,
        lastname : lastname,
        company : company,
        twitter : twitter,
        rank : config.RANK_USER
    });

    return result.nInserted == 1 ? new User(_id, email, false, username, firstname, lastname, company, twitter, config.RANK_USER) : false;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation:

> Insert
>
> Records can be inserted to a collection with insert
>
> `collection.insert(docs[[, options], callback])`

So what you want can be done via **callback** function.

I think you can solve your task

```
User.addUser = function(db, email, username, password, firstname, lastname, company, twitter, callback){
var _id = new mongodb.ObjectID();

db.get('users').insert({
    _id: _id,
    email : email,
    verified : false,
    password : password,
    username : username,
    firstname : firstname,
    lastname : lastname,
    company : company,
    twitter : twitter,
    rank : config.RANK_USER
}, callback);
};
```

So callback function will be called when insertion is completed.

It receive two arguments: error and result.

```
function callback(err, res){
  // some actions
}
```

Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407834/error-when-inserting-a-document-into-mongodb-via-node-js), it can help!

Comment: So is there no way to make it as simple as User.addUser traditionally returning a new user object?  I wanted to do this because it is neater and easier to manage, but if it's not doable then I'll try callbacks instead

Comment: No, you cannot `return` a result of an asynchronous operation (you **can** `return` whatever you want, but the result will obviously not be available, so your options are limited). The closest to this is using a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but it's not the same. Alternatively, once ECMA Sscript 6 is fully supported, you will be able to do this using a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a promise pattern here:

```
return result.then(function( myNewUser ){
   return new User(myNewUser._id, email, false, username, firstname, lastname, company, twitter, config.RANK_USER);
})
```

Comment: Doing this seems to return nothing still.  I even put a console.log inside of the promise callback and nothing was logged.

Comment: Scratch that, I did the most dumb thing possible and put the log after the return.  It seems to be returning the right stuff, but my user object located at `var user = User.addUser(...);` is still undefined.  Does this need a promise too, like `var user = User.addUser(...).then(function(user){return user;});`?

Comment: Yes, you're essentially dealing with promises and async pattern here so you'll have to use callbacks. Depending on what your use-case is, you can for example resolve user requests from the callback.